# How to create a script that is automated and sequential

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, automation, sequential

I'm struggling in trying to create a script in Linux (Terminal-Bash) which is automated and when run it will ask for a input and when that input is added it will create sequential files.

See below:
when script is run, it should show

Which country are you from?
I enter Brazil and wish to see:

Data entered: Brazil1, Brazil2, Brazil3.....Brazil 10

The script needs create a batch of 10 each time it is run i.e.

Which country are you from?
I enter Canada and wish to see:

Canada1, Canada2, Canada3.....Canada10

If brazil entered again: Brazil11, Brazil12....Brazil20 and Brazil21, Brazil22....Brazil30 etc

I do not want to hardcode the numbers, automation is required to create them each time.

**Testing:
**
I have created the script by:

Touch test.sh

I have tried to edit the script by:

vim test.sh

In vim I have made the below changes:

#!bin/bash

echo "Which country are you from"

value=country

value{1..10}

Save vim, when executing script I get this message:

test.sh: line 4: value1: command not found

Can someone please help with the script? I'm completely new to linux and trying to best understand how to create the simplest and most effective process.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is pretty straightforward to implement. You need to use the `read` command to read user input in. You can use the while loop with `-f` to test which files already exist, and then finally the for loop to create those files

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo Hello, what country are you from?

read user_country

n=1

while [ -f "$user_country$n" ]
do
    let "n+=10"
done

for ((i=0; i<10; i++))
do
    file_num=$((i + n))
    touch "$user_country$file_num"
done
```

Comment: `let "N+=10"` can be done as `((N+=10))`. Also, you should use lowercase vars.

Comment: Hi Carson & Diego, thanks for answering to quickly, I have entered line by line what you suggested below:

#!/bin/bas
echo Hello, what country are you from?
N=1
[-f" $USER_COUNTRY$N"]
N+=25
((i=0; i<25; i++))
FILE_NUM=$((i + N))
touch "$USER_COUNTRY$FILE_NUM"

I'm getting the following errors:
smart.sh: line 5: [-f ko1]: command not found
smart.sh: line 7: ((: i=0; i<25; i++: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "; i<25; i++")

Is my input wrong? Apologies as still new to Linux Bash scripting.

Comment: copy/paste their script into your file. Spaces are important in shell scripting. `[-f` is NOT thie same as `[ -f` for instance. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Shellter, I have copied the exact scripting line for line when deploying the script Bash test.sh I am getting this:

test.sh: line 18: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``' &
test.sh: line 19: syntax error: unexpected end of file

I'm really up against a brick wall here, any suggestions?

Comment: If you copied the the 3 "back-tics chars ("\`") at the end, please delete those and try again. Note it is very hard to display a back-tick char in comments, as it is used to convert text to `fixed-font format` (as it I did there, with back-ticks you can't see (-;! ) .

Comment: Thanks Shellter that worked with no errors now BUT when I run the script it does not create a batch of 10 files as I asked originally. When the script is run, it should (say for example I entered Canada) display Canada1, Canada2...all the way to Canada10 but it does not, it only shows my answer (Canada) and nothing further.

 What would you suggest? Thanks for your patience by the way

Comment: It is working for me. The best I can recommend is that you update your question above an use copy/paste to show your trial runs. After each run, add the output of `ls`. (I see files USA1-10 and Canada1-10 in my test). Mouse select that text, paste it in, and from the edit menu (at the top of the edit dialog), click the `{}` tool for correct formatting as `code/data/output/errMsgs`. Leave a msg in comments that you have made the change and I will look at it when I am around). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Shellter, I did not ls to see the results, my mistake, thanks for your expertise and patience.
Thanks Carson to providing the script.